# Start pause and stop C# method from GUI

Tags: c#, methods, event-handling, delegates

I have class method and event

```
public class DefaultVariables
{
    private DataTable SetDataFromSQL()
    {
        var Eventstatus = new BasicEventsHandlersArgs();
        Eventstatus.Status.Task =  BasicEventStatus.Busy;
        Eventstatus.Status.Task_Status = "Please wait while we performing";
        Eventstatus.Status.Task_CurrentProgress = "Verifying Steps...";
        Eventstatus.Status.Task_TotalProgress = "Measuring Source Properties , Destinations Properties and someother(s)";

        Raise_DefaultVariablesProgressUpdate(Eventstatus);

        // Long running SQLs
    }
 
    public event EventHandler<BasicEventsHandlersArgs> Event_DefaultVariablesBasciProgress;

    protected virtual void Raise_DefaultVariablesProgressUpdate(BasicEventsHandlersArgs e)
    {
        Event_DefaultVariablesBasciProgress?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

and I call it in a Windows Forms app like this:

```
DefaultVariables variables = new DefaultVariables();

public EmployeeTag(string UserID)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    variables.Event_DefaultVariablesBasciProgress += Variables_Event_DefaultVariablesBasciProgress;
}

private void Variables_Event_DefaultVariablesBasciProgress(object sender, BasicEventsHandlersArgs e)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    LabDepartmentCount.Text = e.Status.Task_Status.ToString();
    labDesignationCount.Text = e.Status.Task_CurrentProgress.ToString(); ;
    labEmCount.Text = e.Status.Task_TotalProgress.ToString();

    // while (e.Status.Task != BasicEventStatus.Completed) { importToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false; }

    if (e.Status.Task == BasicEventStatus.Busy) 
    {
        importToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false; 
    }

    if (e.Status.Task == BasicEventStatus.Completed) 
    { 
        importToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = true; 
    }
}

private void importToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetDataFromSQL();
}
```

The code is working and raising event as I expected, no error.

I just want to add button on GUI to pause, stop and continue between execution and want to control `SetDataFromSQL`, pause if there is long running code inside and continue from there.

Just like `backgroundworker.cancel()` method.

So how can I pause the execution from GUI button?

How can I pass pause flag to wait until I click continue?

Please help me out

Comment: First of all, I'd probably prefer using `async Task<TResult>` with `IProgress<T>`. Then you could perfectly well support "Stop" by using a `CancellationToken`. Not sure though, how you would go about "pausing". Or why you would want to pause in the first place. But going from there it might be possible. That out of the way: `DoEvents()` in this place is a big fat flying red flag that smells very badly. And you should get rid of it.

Comment: Shouldn't `SetDataFromSQL();` be `variables.SetDataFromSQL();`?...but you've got it set to `private` so that wouldn't work anyways.  How is your code ACTUALLY triggering the process to start? In `// Long running SQLs`, is there any  type of threading going on? Your end goal can be accomplished using various [Thread Synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives) techniques, but the queries need to be running in a different THREAD so that it can be PAUSED indefinitely while it waits for the signal to continue.